# Windows batch script to extract number from HTML code?

Tags: batch-processing

I am looking for some code to extract a number which is expected to be from one to four digits in length from some HTML code.  I have pulled the web page using cURL and used FIND to extract the single line of information I need, but I would like the output to be much cleaner.

Here is an example of the HTML line I'm dealing with:

```
constant_text_here 123 constant_text</h2></td>
```

Does that html code mess things up for batch scripting?  I know nothing about scripting with Windows Batch code.  The number can remain as a string, but it is expected to be between one and four digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%a IN (q25614455.txt) DO SET var=%%a
ECHO var=%var%
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25614455.txt` containing your data for my testing. Sadly, you don't reveal what *constant_text_here* actually is, so honing the procedure is in your bailiwick. The number following `tokens=` will pick a string from the text supplied in the file; had your text been `constant text here` for instance, you'd need to change `tokens=2` to `tokens=4`.

It would also likely be possible to include your curl/find into the procedure and extract your target data in one line, but without sufficient details, a vague general question can at best 
garner a vague response.

Comment: Thanks.  I can adjust the code from there after seeing an example.  The constant text and html code doesn't change on the web page I'm checking.  Only the number changes, and that is the data I'm trying to pull off the web server.

Answer (score 0):

The < and > will give you trouble as they're used to redirect output.

Is using VBscript a possibility?

From the command line:

```
C:\>set myvar=constant_text_here 123 constant_text</h2></td>
```

will output:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

but this will work:

```
C:\>set myvar="constant_text_here 123 constant_text</h2></td>"
C:\>echo %myvar%
"constant_text_here 123 constant_text</h2></td>"

C:\>echo [%myvar:~20,4%]
[123 ]
```

Assuming what interests you can always be found at position 20